# Expert: algorithm to predict next key in a numeric keyboard based on limits (min x max)

Tags: algorithm, keyboard, prediction

I'm trying to make an algorithm that calculates what keys can be pressed in a numeric keyboard, based on limits (min and max values) predetermined. So I can hide those keys that are "unavailable".

Let's supose the value will be from 89 to 120. So what are the "first" keys available? And "second" keys, based on first one ? And so on...

Any tip (or link) will be very welcome.

Comment: How fast must this be? How big are the numbers going to be? For small ranges, you might just build a trie or DFA of all acceptable digit sequences.

Comment: Also, you wouldn't have to build the trie directly. Just say that the 1 branch leads to all the tens, hundreds, thousands, etc. The other branches are built similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a trie data structure for tens, hundreds, thousands.